# Dual Boot with windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

I am trying to dual boot ubuntu with my existing windows 10 system. my system supports UEFI and Legacy support for boot. I created the 20GB free space and installed Ubuntu as dual OS with root and swap partition. then the system asks for EFI partition, I go back and create an EFI partition too. after install finished I was not able to boot into any OS. pc showing insert boot device massage.
can anyone please help me with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both OS's has to be installed in same boot-environment, so if Windows is installed in Legacy boot, Ubuntu has to be too. And opposit, If Windows was installed in/with UEFI, so must Ubuntu be.

Comment: I was not sure of the existing windows is being installed in UEFI or Legacy. Currently using VM for ubuntu. Is there any way to know which environment is used in existing windows? Thanks for your reply.